# One of the applications on Tomcat shutsdown automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, shutdown, tomcat9

We are building services on Spring Boot (2.1.3) framework and deploying multiple applications on a single Tomcat instance (version is given below) as wars. We have been observing that some of the applications on the Tomcat are being shutdown randomly without any exception and with no manual intervention. Does anyone faced the same issue or know the probable reason for the same?

I am not sure if it is relevant but one thing I noticed is, application is idle for couple of hours with no requests.

Tomcat version:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.14
Server built:   Dec 6 2018 21:13:53 UTC
Server number:  9.0.14.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_202-b08
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

UPDATE: Attaching the logs from application log and Catalina log:

```
Application log:
2020-05-11 18:06:17.467  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-05-11 18:06:17.468  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'app.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-05-11 18:06:17.468  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2020-05-11 18:06:17.469  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-05-11 18:06:17.480  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'topicExecutor'
2020-05-11 18:06:17.480  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'topicExecutor'
2020-05-11 18:06:17.485  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.a.e.i.a.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor        : Shutting down the default async job executor [org.activiti.spring.SpringAsyncExecutor].
2020-05-11 18:06:17.485  INFO 15870 --- [activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] o.a.e.i.a.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable       : {} stopped async job due acquisition
2020-05-11 18:06:17.485  INFO 15870 --- [activiti-reset-expired-jobs] o.a.e.i.a.ResetExpiredJobsRunnable       : {} stopped resetting expired jobs
2020-05-11 18:06:17.485  INFO 15870 --- [activiti-acquire-async-jobs] o.a.e.i.a.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable    : {} stopped async job due acquisition
2020-05-11 18:06:17.489  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'primaryTaskExecutor'
2020-05-11 18:06:17.489  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-11 18:06:17.494  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown completed.
2020-05-11 18:06:17.505  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'app'
2020-05-11 18:06:17.508  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-11 18:06:17.514  INFO 15870 --- [Catalina-utility-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.


Catalina log:    
11-May-2020 18:06:17.618 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/app]
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:130)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:608)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:182)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1621)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1149)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1351)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1355)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1333)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.621 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache/to
    mcat/webapps/app.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1621)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1149)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1351)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1355)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1333)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.WarResourceSet@629c5b88]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:714)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4778)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4913)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.WarResourceSet@629c5b88]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:714)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4778)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4913)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)

                                 11-May-2020 18:06:17.622 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache/tomcat
    /webapps/app.war] has finished in [9] ms
    11-May-2020 18:06:20.758 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal acc
    ess: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to atte
    mpt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thr
    own for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1023)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    created a ThreadLocal with key of type [weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal$1] (value [weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal$1@78a01fa6]) and a value of ty
    pe [weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal.ThreadStorage] (value [weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal$ThreadStorage@7800a197]) but failed to remove it when
    the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.621 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache/to
    mcat/webapps/app.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1621)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1149)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1351)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1355)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1333)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.WarResourceSet@629c5b88]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:714)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4778)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4913)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.WarResourceSet@629c5b88]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:714)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4778)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4913)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
            ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/apache/tomcat/webapps/app.war (Permission denied)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
            at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)

                                 11-May-2020 18:06:17.622 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache/tomcat
    /webapps/app.war] has finished in [9] ms
    11-May-2020 18:06:20.758 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal acc
    ess: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to atte
    mpt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thr
    own for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1023)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.527 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [app] register
    ed the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has
    been forcibly unregistered.
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.530 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [app] appea
    rs to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace o
    f thread:
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:70)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.531 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [app] appea
    rs to have started a thread named [weblogic.timers.TimerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread
    :
    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerThread.doWait(TimerThread.java:115)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerThread.access$000(TimerThread.java:21)
    weblogic.timers.internal.TimerThread$Thread.run(TimerThread.java:291)
    11-May-2020 18:06:17.532 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [app] appea

    11-May-2020 18:06:17.535 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [app] appea
```

Comment: Show logs displaying the shutdown occurring.

Comment: Added the logs... also, note that there are multiple applications hosted on the same Tomcat instance. Also, I checked the file existence and permissions. Don't see any issue there.

Comment: What user is Tomcat running as? What are the permissions of the file and folders? Do you have SELinux enabled? If yes, did you specify SELinux rules for Tomcat process and for the file in `app.war` file?